# Mostrar mensaje usuario no existe o no se encuentra registrado con javascript o ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

¿Cómo hago para mostrar un mensaje que me diga `USUARIO NO SE ENCUENTRA REGISTRADO` cuando la persona digite mal el usuario?

Lo que quiero hacer es solamente usar JavaScript o en su defecto AJAX.

Este es el formulario:

```html
<div class="contact-form">
    <img src="{#FS_PATH#}view/img/grado.jpg" class="avatar">
    <div align="center">
        <font color="white" size="+3"> INICIO DE SESIÓN</font>
    </div>
    <form name="f_login" action="index.php?nlogin={$nlogin}" method="post" id="f_login">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">mail_outline</i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su Usuario" name="user" id="user" class="validate" autofocus
                    required="" />
                <label for="user" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Usuario</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <i class="material-icons prefix">lock</i>
                <input type="password" placeholder="Ingrese su Contraseña" name="password" id="password"
                    class="validate" required="" maxlength="32" />
                <label for="password" data-error="wrong" data-success="right">Contraseña</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
                <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn waves-effect waves-light col s12 blue">Iniciar
                    Sesión</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Funcion:

```
private function log_in_user(&$controller_user, $nick, $password, $ip)
{
    $user = $this->user_model->get($nick);
    if (!$user) {
        $this->core_log->new_error('El usuario o contraseña no coinciden!');
        $this->user_model->clean_cache(TRUE);
        $this->cache->clean();
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (!$user->enabled) {
        $this->core_log->new_error('El usuario ' . $user->nick . ' está desactivado, habla con tu administrador!');
        $this->core_log->save('El usuario ' . $user->nick . ' está desactivado, habla con tu administrador!', 'login', TRUE);
        $this->user_model->clean_cache(TRUE);
        $this->cache->clean();
        return FALSE;
    }

    /**
    * En versiones anteriores se guardaban las contraseñas siempre en
    * minúsculas, por eso, para dar compatibilidad comprobamos también
    * en minúsculas.
    */
    if ($user->password != sha1($password) && $user->password != sha1(mb_strtolower($password, 'UTF8'))) {
        $this->core_log->new_error('¡Contraseña incorrecta! (' . $nick . ')');
        $this->core_log->save('¡Contraseña incorrecta! (' . $nick . ')', 'login', TRUE);
        return FALSE;
    }

    $user->new_logkey();

    if (!$user->admin && !$this->ip_filter->in_white_list($ip)) {
        $this->core_log->new_error('No puedes acceder desde esta IP.');
        $this->core_log->save('No puedes acceder desde esta IP.', 'login', TRUE);
    } else if ($user->save()) {
        $this->save_cookie($user);

        /// añadimos el mensaje al log
        $this->core_log->save('Login correcto.', 'login');

        /// limpiamos la lista de IPs
        $this->ip_filter->clear();

        $controller_user = $user;
        return $controller_user->logged_on;
    }

    $this->core_log->new_error('Imposible guardar los datos de usuario.');
    $this->cache->clean();
    return FALSE;
}
```

Quiero mostrar un mensaje de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado y qué problema o error tienes en base a ese intento?

Answer (score 0):

Bueno lo primordial es tener un formulario para enviar a php, en este caso lo que puedes hacer es tener tu archivo javascript.js,  hacer un addeventListener al boton

puedes usar Jquery o Fetch, yo manejo fetch te dejo la estructura

```
fetch('url-destino-archivo.php')
.then(respuesta => respuesta.json())
.then(respuesta => {  console.log(respuesta) })
```

Entonces en tu archivo de consulta enviada por url. archivo.php

```
if($_POST){
   $usuario = $_POST['name-de-tu-input'];
   $password = $_POST['name-de-tu-input-password'];

   para la consulta a la base de datos puedes USAR PDO Ó MYSQLI 
puedes enviar una funcion ejemplo - funcionBuscar(datos) retorna un true
echo json($dato.)
}
```

Comment: Lo que pasa esque estoy usando un framework llamada Factura Script

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar un php que haga la busqueda del usuario algo como:

```
    <?php
     require 'conexion.php';
     session_start();

Validas que el submit no este vacio

if (isset($_POST['submint'])) {
 $name_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['username_user']);
 $pass_user = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['password_user']);

validas que el usuario no este vacio
  

if ($name_user!="" && $pass_user!="") {

lo buscas en la base de datos 

  $querylogin = "SELECT id_user FROM users WHERE username_user = '$name_user' AND password_user = '$pass_user'";
  $resultl = mysqli_query($conexion,$querylogin);

lo mandas a llamar de la base de datos 
   

$row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($resultl,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
       $countl = mysqli_num_rows($resultl);

Aqui validas que exista ese usuario 
   

if ($countl==1) {
        $_SESSION['user']=$name_user;
        $user=$row1['id_user'];

Aqui le indicas que si el usuario existe te redireccione
    

header("location: ../index.php?cliente=".$_SESSION['user']."&user=".$user);
       }else {

aqui le indicas que si no existe te mande un mensaje de error no existe y te direccione a donde mismo
 

       echo "<script>
                    alert('Error el usuario no existe');
                    window.location= '../login.php'
        </script>";
       }
      }
     }
     ?>
```

Esto es lo que me funciono a mi espero te `sirva`

Comment: Considera explicar tu código, si tienes dudas de como formular una buena respuesta aquí te puedes apoyar: [answer]